# How do I move a row from a table in one database to another?

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, datagridview

So in my program, I have two database.
One is 'CurrentCargo', the other is 'PastOrders'

What I wanted to do is that when the tick box in "CurrentCargo"'s table had been ticked, it will take the variables in the row and move it into the "PastOrders"'s Table.
As shown in the image below:
 [Tick in tick box triggers a movement of row values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6q1m.png)
So this is what I typed for my code:

```
private void CurrentCargoTable_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 9 && e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            bool Check = Convert.ToBoolean(CurrentCargoTable.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value);

            int Index = 0;

            int Code;
            DateTime ImportDate;
            DateTime ExportDate;
            string From;
            string To;
            string TransportMode;
            string Supplier;
            Decimal Cost;
            bool Payed;
            bool Delivered;

            if (Check == true)
            {
                Index = CurrentCargoTable.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

                Code = (int)CurrentCargoTable.Rows[Index].Cells[1].Value;
                ImportDate = (DateTime)CurrentCargoTable.Rows[Index].Cells[2].Value;
                ExportDate = (DateTime)CurrentCargoTable.Rows[Index].Cells[3].Value;
                From = (String)CurrentCargoTable.Rows[Index].Cells[4].Value;
                To = (String)CurrentCargoTable.Rows[Index].Cells[5].Value;
                TransportMode = (String)CurrentCargoTable.Rows[Index].Cells[6].Value;
                Supplier = (String)CurrentCargoTable.Rows[Index].Cells[7].Value;
                Cost = (Decimal)CurrentCargoTable.Rows[Index].Cells[8].Value;
                Payed = false;
                Delivered = false;


                string sql = string.Format("insert into dataGridView1 (Code, Import_Date, Export_Date, From, To, TransportMode, Supplier, Cost, Payed, Delivered) values ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}');", Code, ImportDate, ExportDate, From, To, TransportMode, Supplier, Cost, Payed, Delivered);
                this.tableTableAdapter1.Insert(sql);
                this.tableAdapterManager1.UpdateAll(this.pastOrdersDataSet);
                dataGridView1.Update();
```

But it still doesn't work. I tried to use a message box to see if the variables are storing the right values. And every single one is holding the value I wanted. So I kind of get the part of "reading", but I don't get the part of "writing".

Please help me if anyone knows, thank you.

Comment: Don't work with table values. Work with underlying data. If your underlying data is `List<Model>` then it is simple - `Db2Prsister.Insert(myList[idx]); Db1Prsister.Delete(myList[idx]);`. You just effectively moved record from one db to another. Of course, EF would help with speed of development of this

Answer (score -1):

The following will will work if there is no previous data (may be you need to check for this before executing)

```
string sql = string.Format(@"Select * into CurrentCargo  from PastOrders Where 
PastOrders.Code = '{0}'", Code);
```

Comment: @LignerPoi be aware that you'll have to run an additional `DELETE` statement in case you want to also remove the row from `CurrentCargo`.

Comment: Your code seems to work...half way? ............red lines are under the ones that are not in string, for example ImportDate and ExportDate which are in DateTime. If I try to convert it into DateTime by using "Convert.ToDateTime()",  there will be no more red lines. However when I run the debugging, it will pop up "An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code"